# Make Sequelize use returning: true for all mutations

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Is there any way to make all create/update/destroy operations in Sequelize use `returning: true` automatically?

I've tried putting it in `defaultScope` but it doesn't seem to take effect.

Comment: Did you try passing `returning: true` globally? I mean when you pass your `db` config.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari you mean in the options I pass to `new Sequelize`? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes, `new Sequelize` takes a `config` object. You define other configurations on `config.defin = { returning: true }` not sure if it works, but worth trying.

Comment: Guess I could try it, but even if such a thing exists, it wouldn't be official documented API, so maybe not good to rely on it.

Comment: It's documented somewhere I don't remember, you pass other things this ways like to make `createdAt: created_on` others.

Comment: Are you talking about [`Model.init`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-init) or [`Sequelize.constructor`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor)?

Comment: (`returning` isn't a documented root option for either one though)

Comment: I see `returning` is listed there, why don't you just try.

Comment: No, it's not listed in either of the links I provided, I'm tired of talking about this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to configure this, but you can quite easily implement a "hack", by modifying the original Model methods. In the file where you create your Sequelize instance, create a reference to the original Model method you want to modify, and then "substitute" it with a modified function, that calls the original:

```
 const originalCreate =  Sequelize.Model.create//Create a reference to the original function.

     Sequelize.Model.create =async  function(values,options={}){              

           const opt = {...options,returning:true}//Intercept the options and append "returning"
           console.log(values,opt)
           const data =await  originalCreate.call(this,values,opt);//Call the original function.
           return data;               

       }


const sequelize = new Sequelize(...)//Create the instance...
```

You can repeat this interception for every Model method you want to modify.

Note that "returning" works only for Postgres, according to the docs.

Comment: well, of course a better approach than this would probably be to subclass `Model`.  But there are a lot of methods to modify (including all the dynamically generated association methods) so I was hoping there might be global switch.